# Visualizing the loss landscape in deep NN to compare optimization methods

Tags: neural-networks, loss

I'm comparing 2 optimization algorithms for deep neural nets through visualizing the loss landscape. The visualization method is described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09913).

Besides the qualitative observation that how trajectory moves w.r.t. the loss level-sets, are there any quantitive measures to compare the two methods?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- speed of convergence
- stability/variance w.r.t to the initial random seed (or other sources of variance like learning rate)
- presence/number of saddle points in your loss landscape